# Navigate to project quickly?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm working on a HUGE solution (> 300 projects) in Visual Studio 2013.

**What's the fastest way to navigate to a project given its name (or part of it)?**

Currently I use the 'Collapse All' button in the solution explorer and scroll, scroll, scroll.

FWIW I use Resharper (v8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (Go to file/folder), and then just start typing the project name.  Once you've found your match, hit enter and it will be focused in the Solution Explorer.

I'm using Resharper 7, but I think this would work the same in 8.

Answer (score 0):

With ReSharper 8, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (Go to Everything/Type..).

The functionality has been extended greatly from earlier versions,so that it shows much more than just the names of classes.

It now will also show matching Project names, JavaScript, SQL objects(e.g. stored procs).

Comment: The default mapping for 'Go to Everything' in Re# v.8 is Ctrl-T. (Ctrl-N opens the 'New File' dialog.) It does work well - I usually search the first letters of the project followed by '*.cspr'

Comment: Ah I see the issue; you're using VS Key mappings, but I use the overriding ReSharper keyboard settings.